# Twisted - pass result to mutiple callbacks

Tags: python, callback, twisted, deferred

I have two callback functions B, C and I would like them process the result of function A returning Deferred (A->B->C). Normally, I would join them into one but for a reason, I can't do that.

From what I know, twisted callback pipeline processes return of previous callback.
Solution is obviously add B, C as callbacks to A, and pass original return of A to B and through return to C. Is there a better way to do it, something like *reverse DeferredList*?

Comment: what is the problem with `A().addCallback(B).addCallback(c)` ?

Comment: It's not a problem, it's just uncomfortable: C was designed to work with same result as B and these functions are used throughout whole system. Never mind, I've already rewritten these arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or maybe you could use `inlineCallbacks`

```
`
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks

@inlineCallbacks
def doThing():
     result = yield A()
     B(result)
     C(result)

     # or if it is a function returning a deferred
     yield B(result)
     yield C(result)
`
```